# Interesting Flink Problem - How to restore state in Flink if the task manager fails in order to gurantee exactly once processing?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Hi I am new to Flink and trying to figure out some best practices with the following scenerio:

I am playing around with a Flink job that reads unique data from multiple CSV files. Each row in the CSV is composed of three columns: userId, appId, name. I have to do some processing on each of these records (capitalize the name) and post the record to a Kafka Topic.

The goal is to filter out any duplicate records that exist so we do not have duplicate messages in the output Kafka Topic.

I am doing a keyBy(userId, appId) on the stream and keeping a boolean value state "Processed" to filter out duplicate records.

The issue is when I cancel the Task Manager in the middle of processing a file, to simulate a failure, it will start processing the file from the beginning once it restarts.

This is a problem because the "Processed" State in the Flink job is also wiped clean after the Task Manager fails!

This leads to duplicate messages in the output Kafka topic.

How can I prevent this?

I need to restore the "Processed" Flink state to what it was prior to the Task Manager failing. What is the best practice to do this?

Would Flink's checkpointed function https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#checkpointedfunction help? I think not because this is a keyed stream.

Things to consider:

1. Flink Checkpointing is already enabled.
2. K8 pod for Task Manager (can be scaled very fast) and Parallelism is always > 1.
3. Files can have millions of rows and need to be processed in parallel.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to read up on Flink's fault tolerance mechanisms, checkpointing & savepointing. https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/learn-flink/fault_tolerance/ and https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/checkpoints/ are good places to start.

I think you could also achieve your deduplication easier by using Table API/SQL. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/deduplication/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use flink's managed keyed state, which Flink will maintain in a manner that is consistent with the sources and sinks, and Flink will guarantee exactly-once behavior provided you setup checkpointing and configure the sinks properly.

There's a [tutorial on this topic in the Flink documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/learn-flink/etl/#stateful-transformations), and it happens to use deduplication as the [example use case](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/learn-flink/etl/#an-example-with-keyed-state).

For more info on how to configure Kafka for exactly-once operation, see [Exactly-once with Apache Kafka](https://www.docs.immerok.cloud/docs/cookbook/exactly-once-with-apache-kafka-and-apache-flink/).

Disclaimer: I wrote that part of the Flink documentation, and I work for Immerok.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I've implemented KeyedCoProcess Function to connect 2 Kafka streams and I'm using PVC to store the state. The job works as expected but if the job manager restarts, it is unable to restore the state. The only difference in my implementation, compared to the one in the documentation is that I've not implemeneted the "open" method.

Comment: How are you setting up the state without using the open method? And in what way does restoring the state fail?

Comment: Never mind -- I found your follow-up question.